# VBScript: create folder in users mailbox using Outlook fails

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, exchange-server

I try to create a folder in a users inbox using Outlook:

```
' works fine:
Set oOutlookSession = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oNamespace = oOutlookSession.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Call oNamespace.Logon("", "", False, True)
Set oRecipient = oNamespace.CreateRecipient("John.doe@companyA.com")
Call oRecipient.Resolve()

' here: problem if user has multiple email adresses, 
'       working fine if user has only one email address:
Set oInbox = oNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecipient, 6)

' working fine if inbox was retrieved
Call oInbox.Folders.Add("myFolder")
```

The whole script is working fine if the user has only ONE SMTP address (John.doe@companyA.com). If he has another SMTP-address in his Exchange profile (like John.Doe@companyB.com) I get an error here.

I know that the prefix (everything before the '@') in both SMTP-addresses is exactly the same. But even if I try it with the other SMTP-Address I get the same error:

```
Hex(Err.Number) = &h8004010F  ' i.e. MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help, it's really frustrating...

Comment: I just tested your code with a recipient that has several SMTP addresses. It works without a problem. I suspect the "multiple addresses" explanation is a red herring. Here's a tip: Use Outlook and the integrated VBA-IDE to debug your code. That's way more convenient than MsgBox based debugging in VBScript.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use vbscript and not vbs. I switched over using the displayName of the user. This works great if I start the VBS-Script with a doubleclick. If I use a Task calling that vbs-Script I get the same error (using highest priviliges and the same user context).

Comment: I know that you have to use VBScript in the end, my suggestion is to use the VBA IDE for *development and debugging*. VBScript is compatible to VBA, so at least you get to use half-decent tools to do the work. -- If you use a task, maybe you are unable to access the MAPI session properly because of script security? On my machine at least there's a security popup I have to confirm when I run this script.

Comment: You can deactivate it in Outlook security Options.

Comment: So if your task really runs fine for some recipients and you get an error for others, then I have no idea. :/

Comment: I only get errors when I run it as a task for recipients that have more than one SMTP-Address. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code running as a scheduled task? Outlook (just like any other Office app) cannot be used in a service.

Comment: It is, but only works for users with only one Mailbox.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the EX type address instead of SMTP?

Comment: I gave up and used a powershell script and EWS instead, thank you anyway.